# Is it possible to make the enum generates its values automatically

Tags: c#, enums

From [this sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag.aspx) on MSDN:

```
[Flags] 
public enum Pet {
   None = 0,
   Dog = 1,
   Cat = 2,
   Bird = 4,
   Rabbit = 8,
   Other = 16
}
```

Is there anyway to let the enum generates its values automatically  ?

Comment: presumably and still have them as the appropriate bit values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you really *want* a "flags" enum, there's no automated way of doing this, no. The `Pet` example doesn't seem like a good fit for flags, but I'm assuming that's just an unfortunate choice of example. One option which reduces the possibility for error *slightly* is to use bit operations:

```
[Flags] 
public enum Pet {
   None = 0,
   Dog = 1 << 0,
   Cat = 1 << 1,
   Bird = 1 << 2,
   Rabbit = 1 << 3,
   Other = 1 << 4
}
```

If everything uses bit shifting, you know you won't accidentally end up with a value which is actually multiple bits.

Comment: This is the correct answer. As for why the Pet enum has the flags attribute, I imagine they're trying to capture the situation where a person has multiple pets.

Comment: @Cody: So someone can have a cat and a dog, but not two cats? Poor representation, IMO...

Comment: Maybe they are trying to store the ingredient list for the latest Brundlepet?

Answer (score 0):

Just don't put in the equals sign and the value.

For exmaple,

```
enum Days {Sat, Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri};
```

is one of the examples on the MSDN website ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032(v=vs.80).aspx )

Comment: That won't work here, the values are flags, not sequential numbers

Comment: Thanks, I obviously didn't understand the question well enough!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just leave them away:

```
public enum Pet {
   None,
   Dog,
   Cat,
   Bird,
   Rabbit,
   Other
}
```

But this way you should not decorate the enum with the flags attribute because the values cannot be combined anymore in a meaningful way.

Comment: The second part of your answer seems to make this a non-answer. If they're trying to automatically generate the values for an enum with the `FlagsAttribute` applied (which is in fact what the example shows), it isn't going to happen.

Comment: @Code Gray: Or he added the flags attribute without knowing that it can be left away. A pet cannot be a dog and a cat.

Comment: @ PVitt: No, I know that I it can be lefted. Actually it's my fault, I had to write it in the question.